# Starts with an R

Tags: riddle, limerick

> A fashionable part of the blues
>   I am whatever you don't choose
>   I start with an R
>   My messages go far
>   But maybe just after this snooze.

What am I?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are

> A rest

A fashionable part of the blues

> A "rest" is a musical term (it basically means "don't play for X beats"). As pointed out in the comments, rests are the key to the syncopation that makes jazz/blues music sound cool.

I am whatever you don't choose

> That's "the rest"

I start with an "R"

> Yep!

My messages go far

> "REST" is an architectural style for creating and linking web services

But maybe just after this snooze

> A "rest" can mean a brief sleep

Comment: You got the right answer, but the first line can be more _fashionable_.

Comment: Regarding the first line: rot13(Erfgf ner gur xrl gb gur flapbcngvba gung znxrf wnmm + oyhrf fbhaq pbby naq uvc -> snfuvbanoyr?)

Comment: Maybe it's a bit too much of a joke, but ... the rot13(unys erfg [ybbxf yvxr n ung](https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/98898-200.png)). I like your interpretation too, though. So.. we're good. :)

Answer (score 4):

Are you:

> **Reject**?

A fashionable part of the blues

> Many Blues songs are about rejection.

I am whatever you don't choose

> What you don't choose, you reject.

I start with an R

> Reject starts with an R!

My messages go far

> You can reject a telephone call with a message. Or it might refer to rejected email messages which do seem to bounce around all kinds of servers before you get them back.

But maybe just after this snooze.

> 'Snooze' is a way of rejecting an alarm.

Comment: Darn it, you beat me to it. +1

Comment: Oooh close one! The messages one feels like a bit of a stretch to me.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Ah, there's only one right answer. But thanks, I thought it was a a good fit.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> A refrain

A fashionable part of the blues

> A musical refrain, i.e. the chorus

I am whatever you don't choose

> To refrain from, to not choose to do something

I start with an R

> Yep

My messages go far

> most song's refrains convey a message, concept or idea

But maybe just after this snooze.

> refrain can mean to sit out or decline to participate

Comment: An interesting alternative! The second one is addressing the action and not the thing, but otherwise, I like how well this fits.

Answer (score 2):

It could be:

> Rhythm.

A fashionable part of the blues

> Rhythm is used in blues a lot

I am whatever you don't choose

> You can find rhythm without thinking

I start with an R

> **R**hythm

My messages go far

> Rhythm sends a message in the form of a song

But maybe just after this snooze.

> Might just be a line to make it a limerick

Comment: Good attempt! Doesn't quite fit on some of the clues.

Answer (score 1):

Could you be

> **Area**?

`A fashionable part of the blues`

> Area is a fashionable part of [*Pablo Picasso's* **Blue** Period](https://www.pablopicasso.org/blue-period.jsp), as he painted many blue paintings in his time (which required **area** to paint on). Also, painting is a form of art, and the word **area** is part of the word **art** in terms of spelling.

`I am whatever you don't choose`

> When you don't choose to do something, it leaves **room** for you to choose something else. (e.g. "room for improvement".) Room $\to$ area.

`I start with an R`

> R $\to$ **are** and **are**a begins with "are".

`My messages go far`

> You would have to be quite **far up** in the sky to read messages that use a huge amount of area of land (e.g. "SOS").

`But maybe just after this snooze.`

> **Areas** of your brain require **rest**, especially to read and write (messages).

Comment: I appreciate the effort to make this work. Clever attempt!

Comment: @IanMacDonald thanks. I look forward to more of your riddles, assuming you will make some more ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> **Radio**

A fashionable part of the blues

> Where's the hippest source of blues? Radio was integral to spreading and popularizing the blues from the rural Southern states to the urban North

I am whatever you don't choose

> How much choice do you have over a DJ's playlist?

I start with an R

> like Radio

My messages go far

> Longwave radiation!

But maybe just after this snooze.

> Good morning radio alarm, reach out and hit the snooze for another 10 Zzzzs

Comment: Hello! Welcome to the **Puzzling Stack Exchange (PSE)**. I like your answer a lot because it is clever and funny, too, so $+1$. Since you are new to *Puzzling.SE*, I recommend you visit the [**Help Center**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help). You seem to know how to provide a good and well-informed answer, but you have not asked any questions yet, so I suggest that you go [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and then [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Otherwise, great answer once again, and keep puzzling! $$\stackrel{\bullet\,\bullet}{\smile}$$